# Drawing rectangle that is some percent of drawing-panel

Tags: java, swing, awt, jpanel, java-2d

I want to draw rectangle that is only specified percent high of panel im drawing it on, and when i resize the panel it should resize itself. But my problem is that drawRect() accepts only integers so when i try to draw rectangle for example 45% of panel height it gets converted to 0 if panel height is less than 100.

My code is very simple so you can try it out.
Here is my code:

```
public class Drawer extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
            g.fillRect(10,this.getHeight()-this.getHeight()/100*45, 100, this.getHeight()-this.getHeight()/100*45);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also look into using an `AffineTransform`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.getHeight()-(45*this.getHeight())/100
```